# AJAX call not working in WP based site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

This is my first time calling AJAX from within jQuery so please bear with me here.  I have a JSON file where I have formatted all of my data, and would like to simply call the JSON file and append some of the data to my HTML.

I should let everybody know that I am using Wordpress as a backbone for the site, though the PHP-based framework is not being utilized at all to my knowledge in this call, I did try and write out my URL to make sense within the jQuery.  All of the id's in the slugArray array exist within my HTML.

OK!  So:

JSON file can be seen here: http://bmgz.rtcgraphics.com/wp-content/themes/bmgz/data/whatwedo.json

jQuery:

```
var slugArray = [
    '#project-management',
    '#economic-incentives',
    '#site-selection',
    '#stakeholder-engagement-and-events',
    '#lobbying-and-advocacy',
    '#public-policy-and-issues-management',
    '#digital-communications',
    '#event-and-trade-show-materials',
    '#presentation-and-print-design'
]

function getWWD(){
    for (i=0; i<=slugArray.length; i++) {
        var selection = slugArray[i];
        $(selection).click(function(){
            $.getJSON('wp-content/themes/bmgz/data/whatwedo.json', function(result){
                alert("It works!");
                var entry=result.whatwedo[0].id;
                console.log(entry);
                });
            });
        }
    };

getWWD();
```

When I run this, I don't get anything, not even my alert.  I was getting a 404 error when I typed in the URL wrong for the $.getJSON request, so I know the computer is reading it at least partly. Thanks guys!  I appreciate any input!

Comment: When you debug this, where does it fail?  Are the `click` handlers assigned to anything?  When you click the elements, is `getJSON` executed?  Is the request sent to the server?  What is the server's response?  You need to do *some* debugging here.

Comment: The click handlers are working fine! When I put a console.log in before the $.getJSON request, I can see a log to the console.  When I look at the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools, I see my file as GET request, so it's picking up my file, it's just not alerting anything after it gets it.

Comment: there is a specific way to use ajax with wordpress, if you google it you will find loads on it.

Comment: RESOLVED:  I'm an idiot.  Code was failing because I didn't validate my JSON!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var slugArray = [
    '#project-management',
    '#economic-incentives',
    '#site-selection',
    '#stakeholder-engagement-and-events',
    '#lobbying-and-advocacy',
    '#public-policy-and-issues-management',
    '#digital-communications',
    '#event-and-trade-show-materials',
    '#presentation-and-print-design'
]

function getWWD(){
    for (i=0; i<=slugArray.length; i++) {
        var selection = slugArray[i];
        $(selection).click(function(){
            $.getJSON('http://bmgz.rtcgraphics.com/wp-content/themes/bmgz/data/whatwedo.json', function(result){
                alert("It works!");
                var entry=result.whatwedo[0].id;
                console.log(entry);
                });
            });
        }
    };

getWWD();
```